# how to declare such a java class?

Tags: java, generics

the following java class declaration is incorrect:

```
public class BookKeeping<T extends Transaction<K extends Money>> { ... }
```

here, one cannot use the generic declaration `K extends Money`.

my question is why this declaration is not allowed? And how should one declare such a class with java generics?

**solution**

```
class Money {

}

class Dollar extends Money {

}

class Transaction<T extends Money> {

}

public class BookKeeping<K extends Money,T extends Transaction<K>> {
    public void foo () {
        Dollar d = new Dollar();
        Transaction<Dollar> t = new Transaction<Dollar>();
        BookKeeping<Dollar, Transaction<Dollar>> b = new BookKeeping<Dollar, Transaction<Dollar>>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler should tell you why it is not allowed.

Comment: If you are having trouble interpreting the error you are getting, googling it may very well lead you to the answer.

Comment: @VanDarg it's not easy to search some obscure generic issues of java :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the generic parameters and the appropriate constraints and then use them for any anything additional.

```
public class BookKeeping<K extends Money, T extends Transaction<K>> { ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

`public class BookKeeping<K ,T extends Transaction<K extends Money>> { ... }`

You need to "declare" the K generic before you can nested or use it. Its the same rule as local variables.

Comment: Right idea, but not quite right - BookKeeping<K extends Money, T extends Transaction<K>>

Comment: Also it's not the same rules as local variables exactly - `K` can be declared after `T`, the order doesn't matter.